# EntityFramework sort list by roles

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

use **EntityFramework**  I have a two roles [A,B] and i have a  list of the users :

```
USER  => role
-------------
USER1 => A
USER2 => A
USER3 => A
USER4 => B
USER5 => B
USER6 => A
USER7 => A
USER8 => B
```

My expected ordering output is (USER1, USER4 , USER2 , USER5 , USER6 , USER8 , USER7).

Comment: And where is User3 should be?

Comment: I'm just talking about ordering  by roles (A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B)

Answer (score 0):

You can user OrderBy to sort the list by the role. Something like the following:

```
var sortedUsers = MyContext.Users.OrderBy(u => u.Role);
```

Comment: My expected ordering output is (USER1=> A , USER4=> B , USER2 => A, USER5=> B , USER6 => A, USER8=> B , USER7=> A).